# SSAS combine multiple date dimensions for end user

Tags: sql-server, ssas, powerbi

using SQL Server 2016 and VS2015.
We have a cube with many fact tables in - each one with many dates in.  Created date, modified date, target date, scheduled date, completed date etc.  So, now our users are experimenting with PowerBI and are presented with a seemingly endless list of date dimensions to choose from.  We have implemented a naming convention which helps to group them together,

- Service Requests create date
- service requests complete date
- Communication create date
- communication modified date 
  Etc.

However, is there a cleaner way in SSAS to have these, maybe grouped together inside a folder or something - just so that it looks a lot tidier moving forward.  Please see below image.

Ideally I was looking to group them together inside the cube so that when they get rendered in PowerBI they are inside an ">" like below.

Any suggestions please?

[image]

Comment: Are you talking about Multidimensional or Tabular SSAS model?

Comment: Thanks @Jigar, multidimensional.

Comment: You can group queries in query editor, however this doesn't seem to have any effect in report viewer. The only solution I can think of is to rename queries (add a category prefix) and hide unneeded ones. (in powerbi)

Comment: Alternatively, instead of importing your data as is, you could look into writing queries to import smaller number of joined, "flat" tables (where possible and appropriate), so that it's easier to manage in powerbi.

Comment: Thankyou @user5226582, yes, I guess I am going to hide the ones that are unnecessary.  Thanks for your suggestions.